Search target file for terms saved in a .txt or .csv and re.findall?
relatively new to python and coding, but I think I've slammed my head against the wall enough for this one. I've come to stack overflow for sage advice.
I am writing a program that will search through a target folder for predefined terms stored in a "keyterms.csv." keyterms.csv has one column of words and phrases separated by a newline, nothing else. When a word or phrase from the keyterms file is found in a file in the target directory, the program returns the name of the culprit file(s) with number of entries of the keyterm found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
count = len(re.findall(self.ktxt, ttxt))
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

so I think the answer is obvious that re.findall only works with strings or something that spits out only strings, and will not work with dicts, lists or anything else like that. I have tried several snippets of code from SO to split the read file into individual strings to feed into re.findall, to no avail. Should I be feeding the strings into an array or something and for.each the array? not sure what exactly I'm missing.
disregard my copious print statements, just using them to trace what's going on.
def read_key and def find are where the problem lies as far as I can tell. I have tried splitting self.ktxt = list(reader) intro strings and sending it to def find in several ways but maybe I just fundamentally don't understand what's going on with it.
import os
import re
import csv


class FindKterms:

    def __init__(self, path, query):
        self.path = path
        self.query = query
        self.ktxt = {}
        self.searched = {}
        print('def init complete ...')

    def read_key(self):
        print('opening keyterms.csv')
        with open(self.query, newline='', encoding='utf_8') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\n')
            self.ktxt = list(reader)

    def find(self):
        if self.path[-1] != '/':
            self.path += '/'
            print('Appended "/" to given filepath')
        print('starting find function ...')
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(self.path):
            for file in files:
                print('Searching: ' + file + ' ...')
                f = open(root + file)
                ttxt = f.read()
                f.close()
                print('successfully read and closed ' + file)

                count = len(re.findall(self.ktxt, ttxt))
                if count > 0:
                    self.searched[root + file] = count

    def get_results(self):
        return self.searched

the main() seems to work fine calling the functions and moving data around.is calling the functions and seems to work fine. Just the strings from keyterms.csv need to be used as a match case for re.findall across the target directory.
thanks for any help, I feel like I'm right there but the solution eludes me.

The first argument to re.findall() is supposed to be the target pattern you're searching for.  Why are you passing a dictionary as that argument?

You should use one of the techniques shown here to do the replacements

Why are you using the csv module? What do you know or assume (if anything) about the files observed by walking the given "path"?

@JohnGordon I had looked at re.findall for a while and came to believe that if I set things up correctly, I could feed a set of strings into it from the dictionary and compare that with my dataset. after this post, I'm starting to realize that I completely misunderstand re.findall. @SIGHUP at some point I would like to add a second column for term weighting, in which case I will likely be using pandas. Otherwise I would have left it as a .txt for ease of use. the files walked will almost certainly be in a .txt and I will process them to become stripped of anything but strings.

Although keyterms.csv has a .csv extension there's no reason to treat it as a CSV file as it just has one word (term) per line. Therefore you can just open it, read a line at a time and build your query (regular expression).
Let's say we have keyterms.csv that looks like this:
ghi
xyz
abc

Then, in a directory called data we have 3 files - a.txt, b.txt and c.txt with the following contents:
ghi
ghi
abc
zzz

ghi
abc
abc
zzz

ppp

Now the class can be as follows:
import re
from pathlib import Path
from collections import Counter

class FindKterms:
    def __init__(self, path: Path, query: Path):
        self._path = path # directory to be searched
        self._query = query # file containing list of terms to be searched for
        assert self._path.exists() and self._path.is_dir()
        assert self._query.exists() and self._query.is_file()
    @property
    def terms(self) -> re.Pattern:
        if not hasattr(self, "_terms"):
            with self.query.open() as q:
                qt = set(q.read().split())
                p = "|".join(qt)
                self._terms = re.compile(rf"({p})")
        return self._terms
    @property
    def path(self) -> Path:
        return self._path
    @property
    def query(self) -> Path:
        return self._query
    def process(self) -> dict[str, Counter]:
        result = {}
        for file in self.path.glob("*"):
            with file.open() as fd:
                if f := self.terms.findall(fd.read()):
                    result[file.name] = Counter(f)
        return result

path = Path("~/data").expanduser()
query = Path("~/keyterms.csv").expanduser()

print(FindKterms(path, query).process())

Output:
{'b.txt': Counter({'abc': 2, 'ghi': 1}), 'a.txt': Counter({'ghi': 2, 'abc': 1})}

Thus we can see that b.txt has 2 counts of 'abc' and 1 of 'ghi', a.txt has 2 counts of 'ghi' and 1 of 'abc'. The file c.txt does appear in the output because it doesn't contain any of the key terms

This appears to work great, although I'm going to have to sit and digest what's going on. in the method "terms" you have if not hasattr(self, "_terms") and is referenced later in the method as self._terms. in pycharm it shows that _terms is referenced outside init. Why is this?

@3xogenic It's because the linter that you're using doesn't understand what's going on. Try it with mypy. The point is that self._terms is created dynamically - i.e., only after it's been determined that it doesn't exist. It's perfectly valid
